# AngularJS 1.6 Upgrade code to login no longer working with REST?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, spring-boot, angularjs-1.6

I had a project using AngularJS 1.5.8 and the login method worked as followed:

```
$scope.login = function() {
    // creating base64 encoded String from user name and password
    var base64Credential = btoa($scope.username + ':' + $scope.password);
    // calling GET request for getting the user details
    $http.get('user', {
        headers : {
            // setting the Authorisation Header
            'Authorization' : 'Basic ' + base64Credential
        }
    }).success(function(res) {
        $scope.password = null;
        if (res.authenticated) {
            $scope.message = '';
            // setting the same header value for all request calling from
            // this application
            $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + base64Credential;
            AuthService.user = res;
            $rootScope.$broadcast('LoginSuccessful');
            $state.go('dashboard');
        } else {
            $scope.message = 'Login Failed!';
        }
    }).error(function(error) {
        $scope.message = 'Login Failed!';
    });
};
```

This was getting the info from database using spring boot with this Request

```
@RequestMapping("/user")
    public Principal user(Principal principal) {
        return principal;
    }
```

The code has to be updated to run on AngularJS 1.6.8 so I've been following tutorials I have found online etc, and now have this:

```
$scope.login = function() {
    // creating base64 encoded String from user name and password
    var base64Credential = btoa($scope.username + ':' + $scope.password);
    // calling GET request for getting the user details
     $http({
          url: 'user',
          method: 'GET',
          headers : {
                // setting the Authorisation Header
                'Authorization' : 'Basic ' + base64Credential
            }
        })
        .then(function onSuccess(res) {
        $scope.password = null;
        if (res.authenticated) {
            $scope.message = '';
            // setting the same header value for all request calling from
            // this application
            $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + base64Credential;
            AuthService.user = res;
            $rootScope.$broadcast('LoginSuccessful');
            $state.go('dashboard');
        } else {
            $scope.message = 'Login Failed!';
        }
    }, function onError(res) {
        $scope.message = 'Login Failed!';
    });
};
```

Problem is that I keep getting login failed but the users are in the database, and .success has been deprecated so no idea no idea what I've done wrong help greatly appreciated?

Comment: Looks fine to me. What does `res.authenticated` says when you log it??

Comment: Hi Lin thanks for the reply I get an Uncaught ReferenceError as follows VM328:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: res is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:13

Comment: Mhm, have you checked your network tab? Is the request successful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this: [Why are angular $http success/error methods deprecated? Removed from v1.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329384/why-are-angular-http-success-error-methods-deprecated-removed-from-v1-6/35331339#35331339)

The success and error methods are doing some work behind the scenes to unwrap the response.data. So you may need to do

```
if (res.data.authenticated) ....
```

Comment: Yep, with `then/catch` you are getting the raw response back. With `success/error` you were just getting the data element back.

Comment: this worked thanks for the help Kyle and Pop-A-Stash much appreciated